# mysql_real_escape_string with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, mysql-real-escape-string

I am developing a web application using zend framework. For select statements I have used following way.

Ex:

```
public function getData($name)
{
  $sql = "SELECT * from customer where Customer_Name = '$name'";
  return $this->objDB->getAdapter()->fetchAll ($sql);
}
```

This works fine. But If I send customer name as : `colvin's place`,
The query fail. And I know it's because of the single quote.

Earlier I used addslashes PHP function. But I saw it is not a good way to do this. This time I used `mysql_real_escape_string` PHP function.

The issue is it says following warning.

`Warning</b>:  mysql_real_escape_string() [<a href='function.mysql-real-escape-string'>function.mysql-real-escape-string</a>]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

This is because of the `mysql_real_escape_string` function needs a connection to the database opened by `mysql_connect`. My question is how can I use this with *Zend_DB* classes. I need to use custom select queries always. Appreciate your other suggestions if available.

Thank you

Comment: Did yo try using [Zend_DB_Statement](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html)

Comment: I use addslashes() and for integers Intval(). But using addslashes is a bad practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `quote()` function provided by `Zend_Db`:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting.quote

Comment: Thank you. I will check that.

Comment: The reason you don't just post link is because they tend to return 404

Answer (score 2):

You could use parameter binding as well, then the method will look like:

```
public function getData($name)
{
  $sql = "SELECT * from customer where Customer_Name = :name";
  return $this->objDB->getAdapter()->fetchAll ($sql, ['name' => $name]);
}
```

Then your data will be escaped automatically

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, I used this way and is working correctly:

You can use **`quote()`**:

> The **quote**() method accepts a single argument, a scalar string value. It returns the value with special characters escaped in a manner appropriate for the RDBMS you are using, and surrounded by string value delimiters. The standard SQL string value delimiter is the single-quote (').

But quote returns a string with **'string'** (return it inside quotation), for example I get an string from user from a input-text box *(or by URL in GET method)*

```
$string = $this->parameters['string']; // This is like $_POST or $_GET
$string = $this->db->quote($string);
$string = substr($string, 1, strlen($string)-2);   
//The above line will remove quotes from start and end of string, you can skip it
```

Now we can use this `$string`, and it is like what **`mysql_real_escape_string`** returns

Comment: why not simply trim($this->db->quote($string), '"\'");

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this solution works fine for me. I hope this will help.
you can do something like this:

```
$quote_removed_name = str_replace("'","''",$name);
```

then write your query this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from customer where Customer_Name = '$quote_removed_name'";
```

Comment: How do you ensure that there are no other characters that need escaping? `mysqli_real_escape_string()` knows them all, and they depend on the encoding setting of the database connection.

Comment: Furthermore, you don't always want to remove quotes (as yours is effectively doing). The solution you present isn't solving the problem, it's a band-aid for part of the problem.