# Inserting datas to the table in zend2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

iam working with zend 2. Now i want to insert a data which contain single quotes( for eg: application's name).

```
use Zend\Db\Table\AbstractTable;
class ApplicationTable extends AbstractTable {
   protected $_name = "application";
   public function addAlbum($data) {
     $this->insert($data);
   }
}
```

I am using the above code and it shows a syntax error. How can i escape single quotes while processing the query?
 Somebody please help...

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's name' ORDER BY `application_name` ASC' at line 1

Comment: Use quote method in zend and pass inputs to quote method.It will escape the input with proper quotes.

Comment: Iam sorry.I am not familiar with the quote method.Will you please explain how can I use it in the above function?

Answer (score -1):

```
Pass the datas before Inserting 
     Use mysqli_real_escape_string:
  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqliObj,'application's name') or  
  mysql_real_escape_string('application's name') to escape the quotes
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `mysql_` and `mysqli_` string escape functions  won't necessarily work when accessing the database through Zend, because these functions need a database connection to have been established through the relevant `mysql_` and `mysqli_` connection functions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685853/mysql-real-escape-string-with-zend