# ZEND and MySQL - How to search and ORDER BY (sort) relevance?

Tags: php, mysql, search, zend-framework

I'm going to write a simple search on `products` table, and when user is searching for something I use **`product_name LIKE %search_term%`** to search the `product` table. But I need to sort them by relevance.

I'm using ZEND freamwork and my database is MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588710/mysql-how-to-order-by-relevance-innodb-table) someone asked about **how to ORDER BY relevance** in MySQL and someone suggested a good query for that, what you need to do is:

```
 SELECT  product_name
  FROM products
 WHERE product_name like '%search_term%'
 GROUP BY name
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN product_name like 'search_term %' THEN 0
               WHEN product_name like 'search_term%' THEN 1
               WHEN product_name like '% search_term%' THEN 2
               ELSE 3
          END, product_name
```

You will get the **search_term** from user, and have to check it by `mysql_real_escape_string` for security reasons, but we can't use `mysql_real_escape_string` in ZEND. Then we have to check it by ZEND, we use **[`quote()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35595018/3176270)** instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`.

```
//get the search_term what user is looking for:
 $search_term=$this->parameters['search_term'];

//mysql_real_escape_string:
$search_term= $this->db->quote($search_term);
$search_term = substr($search_term, 1, strlen($search_term)-2); //Remove quotation from it.

$query = $this->db->select();
$query->from('products', ['product_id', 'product_name', 'product_sub_name']);
$query->where('product_name LIKE ?', '%'.$search_term.'%');
$query->group('product_name');
$query.="
   ORDER BY CASE WHEN product_name like '$search_term %' THEN 0
        WHEN product_name like '$search_term%' THEN 1
        WHEN product_name like '% $search_term%' THEN 2
        ELSE 3
        END, product_name";

return $this->db->fetchAll($query);
```

This will return what you need, and sort by relevant according to the above SQL query that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1588817/3176270)

If you are going to **limit** your search, you can easily add it to the `$query` variable. Then you will have (For example limit it to 10 results):

```
$query.="
   ORDER BY CASE WHEN product_name like '$search_term %' THEN 0
      WHEN product_name like '$search_term%' THEN 1
      WHEN product_name like '% $search_term%' THEN 2
      ELSE 3
      END, product_name
      LIMIT 0 , 10";
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` was removed in PHP7. The ZF way of quoting strings is the correct one.

Comment: @TimFountain Yes you are right, but I just wanted to give an example, and people know mysql_real_escape_string(), I think this is better to make the answer more clear for them